# She paints in oils vs. She paints with oils

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, difference

> She paints in oils.

> She paints with oils.

What's the difference between them?

Comment: The second uses "with" instead of "in",   Come on Gomadeng. You have been using this site long enough to know that you should show more research and give more context than this.

Comment: The first is idiomatic, the second is not. English uses _in_ to refer to artistic media (drawing in pencil, painting in oils) where you might expect _with_.

Comment: "She paints with oil paints" would be OK and I can find many examples of. "Painting in oil" or "in oils" is idiomatic, though "with oil" would not be wrong. And it's always "she paints *with* a brush" where it's talking about the tool.

Comment: Basic research: Both are used, in is more common. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=paints+in+oils%2C+paints+with+oils&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3

Answer (score 1):

The first is an idiom and the second is literal. Both mean the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

There's no functional difference between these two examples, but that's partly because of the example chosen. "Oils" is both a medium—almost like a "genre", in a sense—and a piece of equipment. But if we said

> "She works in blown glass" vs
> "She works *with* blown glass"

... then there would be a *slight* alteration of meaning. One would mean that she blows glass; the "blown glass" is the type of art she produces. The second seems to suggest that she assembles sculptures *using* glass that has already been blown. Often there is still no functional difference as most glass artists do both. But if we continue the "in" idiom to talk about something that is not a tool in the process:

> "She works in neurology" vs
> "She works *with* neurology"

... then the "with" version, while understandable, becomes a strange choice, because neurology is a field, not a tool.